# View All Changed Files in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I would like to generate a list of all the files that have been modified within my project.  I know I could view the history on the project to get all the changesets and then view each changeset for the files in contains, however, this process would take a long time.  Is there an easier way to generate this list?  The list does not need to be unique, but that would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Source Control Explorer click the folder that contains the files you want to check and hit the Compare Folders button.  This will let you see everything that is different between the server source path and the local path.

Comment: You can also use this to compare the differences between two changesets just like history.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the command line. The only problem is that you also see info about folders that haven't changed.

For example:
tf diff /format:Brief $/Path/To/Solution;C12345~C12355 /recursive

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently and I wrote a program to get the list of files that have changed.  Here's a link to the example I used to create my program 
[Diffing two trees](http://blogs.msdn.com/roberthorvick/archive/2006/04/07/571043.aspx)